# How to select pandas Series values start with a specific text?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select a specific column's value from Pandas DataFrame which value start with a specific text. If True, the next column will be updated with the content from previous column's value.

For example, I have a DataFrame `df_1`, and I want `a2` update with values that `a1` start with `as`.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a1':['amtr1',np.nan,'astr2',np.nan,'gbstr2','mkstr2','gbstr2','astr1'],
                     'a2':[np.nan]*8})
df_1

    a1      a2
0   amtr1   NaN
1   NaN     NaN
2   astr2   NaN
3   NaN     NaN
4   gbstr2  NaN
5   mkstr2  NaN
6   gbstr2  NaN
7   astr1   NaN
```

I want this output.

```
    a1      a2
0   amtr1   NaN
1   NaN     NaN
2   astr2   astr2
3   NaN     NaN
4   gbstr2  NaN
5   mkmk2   NaN
6   gbstr2  NaN
7   astr1   astr1
```

Answer (score 2):

use `loc` with a boolean condition using vectorised [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) with arg `'as'` and select column `'a2'` and assign column `'a1'` values:

```
In [59]:
df_1.loc[df_1['a1'].str.startswith('as', na=False), 'a2'] = df_1['a1']
df_1

Out[59]:
       a1     a2
0   amtr1    NaN
1     NaN    NaN
2   astr2  astr2
3     NaN    NaN
4  gbstr2    NaN
5  mkstr2    NaN
6  gbstr2    NaN
7   astr1  astr1
```

Comment: Alternatively, `(df_1['a1'].str.startswith('as', na=False))` looks more concise.

Comment: @NickilMaveli Yes, I forgot about the `NaN` handling in `str` methods, cheers will update

Comment: Tks, and what if 'as' is an unicode not str? In my real data, there is an error. `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas.`

Comment: what version of python are you using? in python 3 this should just work, otherwise you may need to decode the values first

Comment: It's python  2.7.12. @EdChum

Comment: How is the df created? is it loaded from a csv? if so you can pass an `encoding` param to `read_csv` which should decode on reading, also what version of pandas are you using? Can you not use python 3?